# Gstreamer: How to play video from USB camera with spca561 driver?

Tags: gstreamer, v4l2

I have a Logitech QuickCam Chat camera. When, I run the "v4l2-ctl" tool, I can see that uses the spca561 driver.

I try to use "cheese" tool but it said "No device was found". However, If I run the following, if it works:

```
vlc v4l2:///dev/video0
```

I want to use "gstreamer" tool. I run the following sentence:

```
gst-launch-1.0 v4l2src ! xvimagesink
```

but it's not working.

How can I capture video with gstreamer? Why the tool cheese not capture but if vlc?

Comment: So whats the error if its not working? Anyway, try `videoconvert` between `v4l2src` and `xvimagesink`

Comment: @FlorianZwoch The error in gstreamer is: "internal data stream error", "streaming task paused, reason not-negotiated (-4)". vlc must be loading or specifying how to use the driver but I don't know how to do it with gstreamer. If I use videoconvert, the same error will also occur.

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to use a very old Logitech USB Camera 'Logitech, Inc. QuickCam Express' ... Yes the one from 1999 :-O .
the kernel detect it, and seems to be spca561:  gspca_main: spca561-2.14.0 probing 046d:0928
vlc show nice live video on capture from /dev/video0 : 352x288. 30fps.
guvcview works very well too.

To make it work from gst-launch you can try this :

```
gst-launch-1.0 -vvv v4l2src device=/dev/video0 ! video/x-bayer,width=176,height=144 ! bayer2rgb ! videoconvert ! autovideosink
```

It seems that Gstreamer is wrong on detecting supported formats, but VLC just works... so it's maybe gstreamer problem.